# Wildcard for any string - Telegram-Bot

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

Well, i`m using the telegram bot Updater to handle messages from sent to it. But, I wanted it to respond to any string I give, with an "#" before.

Tried the AnyString method, but didn't work. Also, tried the "*" wilcard thing.

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler

def hello(bot, update):
    update.message.reply_text(
        'Hey {}!'.format(update.message.from_user.first_name))


updater = Updater('770165564:AAEJm45dqDNkOnlso0YK6hQoCbXoCySiHcQ')

updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('*', hello))

updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

When I send some message like "/anything", "/test", the bot will respond with the function I described, saying "Hey {user-name}!".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a PrefixHandler ([docs](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/telegram.ext.prefixhandler.html))

**Examples:**

Single prefix and command:

```
PrefixHandler('!', 'test', callback) will respond to '!test'.
```

Multiple prefixes, single command:

```
PrefixHandler(['!', '#'], 'test', callback) will respond to '!test' and
'#test'.
```

Miltiple prefixes and commands:

```
PrefixHandler(['!', '#'], ['test', 'help`], callback) will respond to '!test',
'#test', '!help' and '#help'.
```